# Python within OSGeo4W installation gives "AttributeError: '_NamespacePath' object has no attribute 'sort'"

Tags: python, osgeo4w, python-3, pip

I have Python 2.7 and Python 3.6 installed via OSGeo4W64 on a Windows 10 x64 machine. I don't have a standalone installation of Python, but I did previously, which may have something to do with the errors I'm getting.

When I try to use python in a CMD window (in Administrator Mode) to run a .py script (in this case a TensorFlow 'getting started' example), I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: '_NamespacePath' object has no attribute 'sort'
```

If I try "where python", this is what I get:

```
C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python36\python.exe
C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\python.exe
```

If I run `C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python36\python.exe`, Python 3.6.4 starts up normally. However if I run `C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\python.exe`, I get the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named site
```

I've checked the environment variables, and the only paths relating to Python are the following (all within System Variables->Path):

```
C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python36\
C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python36\Scripts
C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\
```

On a possibly related note, I'm also having trouble with pip - every time I try to use it I get the following:

```
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"'
```

I know this error has been covered in other questions, but the answers posted have not worked for me, so I'm thinking the pip error is probably a symptom of something else, rather than a problem with pip by itself.